# How to have a function that could return value or promise?

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, promise

Say I want to just return a value if an object is already in my model, but return the result of a endpoint service if not:

```
model.getDoohkyById = function( id ){
    if( this.data ) {
        if( this.data.length > 0) {
            for( var i =0; i < this.data.length; i++){
                if( this.data[i].id === id ){
                    //this returns a value
                    return this.data[i];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // this returns a promise
    return this.service.getBy('id',id);
}
```

How do I structure the first return value in the context of a promise, so that I can do this without the error `object has no method 'then'`?

```
DoohkyModel.getDoohkyById(this.doohkyId).then( function(result){
      that.doohky = result.data;
});
```

Comment: You could *always* return a Promise, such that when you find a cached value you just pre-resolve the Promise so that the callback runs immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `$q` service ([doc here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)) :

```
    model.getDoohkyById = function( id )
    {
       if( this.data ) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            if( this.data.length > 0) {
                for( var i =0; i < this.data.length; i++)
                {
                    if( this.data[i].id === id )
                    {
                        //this returns a value
                        deferred.resolve(this.data[i]);
                        break ;
                    }
                }
            }
            return deferred.promise;
        }

        // this returns a promise
        return this.service.getBy('id',id);
    }
```